# How to add a reload button to an iOS Widget?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

How do I add a reload button to my widget on iOS?

I am aware that Widgets should be readonly and have no interactive elements.
But apps like "Google Maps" do have a reload button.
**How did they achieve that?**

[image: Google Maps Reload Button in Widget]

Adding a simple `Button` to my view will display the button.
But upon pressing it the app will open and the press will not be registered.

Using `deeplinks` will also open my app. I just want a plain reload button.

Comment: The screenshot of the Google widget is showing a pre-iOS 14 style widget that can only be used in the today view. This is an old widget design/architecture which pre-dates SwiftUI. I believe they are still supported, even in iOS 17, but have very different behaviours and code structure to iOS 14+ widgets. In iOS 17, the “new:” style widgets are getting interactivity.

Answer (score 7):

The screenshot shows [Today Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html) widget that is deprecated. Now we use WidgetKit.

I managed to add reload button with AppIntents for iOS 17:

1. Create Intent

   ```
   import AppIntents

   struct ReloadWidgetIntent: AppIntent {
       static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Reload widget"
       static var description = IntentDescription("Reload widget.")

       init() {}

       func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
           return .result()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create reload view

   ```
   import SwiftUI
   import Intents

   struct ReloadView: View {

       var body: some View {
           Button(intent: ReloadWidgetIntent()) {
               Text("Refresh")
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add reload view to your widget view

   ```
   import SwiftUI

   struct MyWidgetView : View {
   var entry: MyTimelineProvider.Entry

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text(entry.date)
               .invalidatableContent()
           ReloadView()
       }
   }
   ```

**.invalidatableContent()** is needed for animation that indicates this view to will be updated. That's the only way I found to animate widget refresh.

Source: [Apple wwdc23](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10028)

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution.  Am I correct in thinking that ReloadWidgetIntent doesn't actually do anything other than satisfy the requirements for AppIntent, and the reason that the widget reloads is because it will always reload after firing any intent?

Comment: @user1930728 yes, it will always reload